# Run task scheduler task 5 min after specific task starting

Tags: windows, taskscheduler

Is there any way to start task after sometime when specific task starts?

Answer (score 0):

Two answers:

1. Put the task in a batchfile, add a wait for 5 minutes and then put the next task.
   In the task scheduler, instead of the task itself, refer to the batchfile.
2. I just see there's something called `INotify cron` (there's a tag `icron` for that). Maybe this can help you.